# ghci :info and haddock on type synonyms

Tags: haskell, ghci, haddock

I have a type synonym like

```
type Events t b = Tb.T t b
```

The underlying type `Tb.T` is an instance of many typeclasses, e.g.

```
instance [safe] (Eq time, Eq body) => Eq (Tb.T time body)
instance [safe] Functor (Tb.T time)
..
```

My type synonym (of course) inherits all these instances. E.g. it is also a Functor:

```
λ> :t flip fmap (undefined :: Events Int String)
flip fmap (undefined :: Events Int String)
  :: (String -> b) -> Tb.T Int b
```

but this fact is not shown in ghci's `:info` command nor in the generated haddock documentation. Also, I'd rather see the return type as `Events Int b` instead of `Tb.T Int b`.

Is there a way to circumvent this?